# Help with identifying web comic with Batman and Robin

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

I read a funny web comic a few months ago where Batman and Robin are in a car and Batman is driving and running over people and Robin expresses concern about how Batman is hurting people and Batman just keeps repeating how he doesn't kill people as you can visibly see how he's maiming people with his car and when Robin presses the issue Batman says something along the lines of "Shut up or I'll not-kill you too".

I think it was based on the Arkham Knight game where you can drive the batmobile around and you can run people over. I think it was also drawn in the style of the [SMBC comics](http://www.smbc-comics.com/) but when I searched that site for Batman comics I couldn't find the comic I was looking for.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.batmanwonderwoman.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4701&start=440

Don't know if this is the original place it was posted, but it's the one.

edited to add: duh, this clearly said nerfnow.com, so I found it at:

http://www.nerfnow.com/comic/1583

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks!